# Why put the non prefixed css3 property last?

Tags: css, cross-browser, vendor-prefix

> When using vendor prefixes, it’s important to keep in mind the order in which you list rules in your declarations.

I already know how vendor prefixes work and why there are needed, but why is good list the vendor-prefixed property first, and the non-prefixed CSS3 property last? I also checked many important sites and they are using this approach:

```
.foo { 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
  border-radius: 10px; //why this is the last one?
  }
```

That's it, why put the actual CSS3 property last? There is a special reason?

Comment: Try googling, you can find an article on it here http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Comment: Thanks @Andy, that's what I was looking for! I think I tried googling with the wrong words ;)

Comment: Anyway, I will check the better answer here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the W3C propriety as  last, new versions of browsers use this version instead of the vendor version. In this way your CSS is read as a normal CSS without vendor prefixes.

In this way new browsers will use the W3C version, updated to the latest specs, if supported by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Useful resource is http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html, maybe you`ll find your answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good reason: [summary of [this post](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) which Andy mentioned]

During the period where browsers support both the vendor prefixes and the actual property - there might be differences in the implementation of the css rule.

Example:

```
.not-a-square {
   /* These do totally different things */
   border-radius: 30px 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 30px 10px;
}
```

> The spec or "real" version will render the top left and bottom right
>   corners at 30px and the top right and bottom left corners at 10px. The
>   vendor prefix will render all four corners with elliptical corners
>   30px wide and 10px tall.